# Looking for the name of a show from the 80's about a man who gets hit by lightning and becomes an agent with a watch thats a meter

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm looking for a show from the 1980s about a man who is struck by lightning and becomes an agent with a watch that is some sort of meter.

Comment: pocket, or wrist-watch?

Comment: I remember this, but pretty sure it was just a TV movie, not a series.

Comment: Did the lightning give him powers? Assuming yes, can you remember any?

Answer (score 6):

Pretty sure this is [The Power Within](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081365/), a 1979 TV movie.

I remember it vaguely - he absorbs the electricity, but in such a way that he's now dependent on it: the meter is to ensure that he doesn't run out, when he does he has to recharge. He can use electricity to cast lightning bolts, Emperor Palpatine style.

Comment: This sounds like it... Here is a YouTube clip showing him asking his buddy about storms in the area, and then using his watch to discharge a lightning blast at an attacker. He also has increased strength.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aE6ZfK2LtY